Early 2000s thriller about a stalker who kills family
I need help identifying a movie about a stalker who messes up with family without them knowing it.
What I remember is this:

A guy keeps watching from his car at a house with a family living in across the street
He breaks into their house and does some little annoying things to break husband and wife relationships from inside. Like he messes with the man's computer, or CDs with music or alarm clock, can't remember all details.
The man and woman start arguing a lot and I think she tells her friends about their tense relationship with her husband, so her friends or parents think he is a bad guy or something like this.
Stalking creep kidnaps the woman leaving a note as it's from her.
Can't remember if he messes up with the man.
Finally the man gets to know that his wife was actually killed but he is the main suspect.
Almost in the end the man recognizes that stalking killer, but he is being killed by police when trying to catch that creep.
Last episode of the movie - stalker is sitting in his car watching at another family across the street in a different neighbourhood.

I've tried to google this movie for two hours without any results. Everyone lists same movies with happy endings by this description so no luck yet.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in?  Are there any descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

This is the plot of the 2011 Canadian thriller 388 Arletta Avenue with Nick Stahl and Mia Kirshner.

An unidentified stalker records video of married couple James and Amy Deakin as they hide their spare key outside their home. When the couple leaves to go jogging, he uses the key to enter their home and set up hidden security cameras in each room. He also makes subtle changes, such as setting their alarm to go off earlier and leaving a mix CD in their car. Amy protests when the alarm wakes her up early, and the two argue over who recorded the mix CD. [...]
When James returns home, he finds a note ostensibly written in Amy's handwriting in which she says that she has left to clear her head. James attempts to contact Amy many times, but she does not answer her calls. [...]
James becomes erratic and paranoid James attempts to confront the stalker, only to realize that he has been framed for [his wife's] murder. While still holding the pistol, James attempts to explain the situation, and the police officer shoots him dead. In his home, the still-unidentified stalker labels his surveillance tape as "388 Arletta Avenue" and sets it beside several other tapes. He then starts the cycle again with a new family.

The movie is presented entirely through surveillance footage. Here's the trailer:




Yay! Thank you, this is it :)
